# Android: How to pass MULTIPLE ArrayList<String> values and one ArrayList<LatLng> from one activity to another in a bundle? Not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist, android-bundle

I have several `List<String>` variables to pass from `Splash` to the Main activity:

**1)** I read somewhere that I can pass them as `ArrayList<String>` from `Splash` to `Main`, and it works... i.e. 
I can receive only the first `ArrayList<String>` variable. In my bundle below, I am not able to receive the second `ArrayList<String>.` (array_list2) Why?

**2)** How to pass `ArrayList<LatLng>` from one activity to another

**First Activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayList("array_list1",(ArrayList<String>)Names);     
b.putStringArrayList("array_list2",(ArrayList<String>)City);
b.putStringArrayList("array_list3",(ArrayList<String>)Country);
b.putStringArrayList("array_list4",(ArrayList<String>)Code);
b.putStringArrayList("array_list5",(ArrayList<LatLng>)coordinates); //ERROR in this line, type mismatch!
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Second Activity:**

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
testList1 = b.getStringArrayList("array_list1");
testList2 = b.getStringArrayList("array_list2"); //THIS gives the same arraylist as testList1 and it is incorrect!
Log.e("TESTLIST1",testList1.toString()); //just using Log.e to view o/p as test
Log.e("TESTLIST2",testList1.toString());
```

Please answer both my questions. None of the other topics helped me, and I spent over 2 hours on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Why casting every object to `ArrayList<String>` ?

Comment: Only ArrayList<String> is supported with method putStringArrayList and there is no other method for List<String>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

putStringArrayList() will not support for ArrayList .

use

```
 putParcelableArrayList();
```

instead of

```
 putStingArrayList();
```

or else you can use direct method of intent.

Change your code somethng like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayList("array_list1",(ArrayList<String>)Names);     
b.putStringArrayList("array_list2",(ArrayList<String>)City);
b.putStringArrayList("array_list3",(ArrayList<String>)Country);
b.putStringArrayList("array_list4",(ArrayList<String>)Code);
```

If you want to pass through bundle object use below line of code.

```
b.putParcelableArrayList("array_list5",(ArrayList<LatLng>)coordinates);
```

Otherwise pass through intent object.

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("array_list5",coordinates);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you please explain for first, and second activities for both List<String> and ArrayList<LatLng>? Is "intent.putExtras(b);" correct?

Comment: intent,putExtras(b); is correct only..LatLng class is a parcelable class so should use putParcelableArrayList("array_list5",coordinates);

Comment: I get the error: "The method putParcelableArrayList(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>)" - also, pl. check the comments in my second activity... I am NOT receiving the second arraylist on the 2nd activity.

Comment: you should not type cast the arraylist. Anyway you are passing arrayList object only na..so type casting is not required.

Comment: I understand using putParcelableArrayList for LatLng. What is the syntax to use it for List<String> ? I have this error with your code - ""The method putParcelableArrayList(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>)""

Comment: no no...you have to use putParcelableArrayList(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>)  for only coordinates, except coordinates arraylist you should use putStringArrayList only.

Comment: Can you please read my question again, 1)The second value "array_list2" is NOT getting received in 2nd activity. Why? (Thanks for posting the first activity's code - how to receive this bundle in the 2nd activity?)

Comment: Please conform that you r adding same or diff data to both the list's. Once checkout the data of Names and City arraylist's by printing it in first activity before passing data to second activity.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. There was a typo in my code... I was displaying testList1.toString() twice.

Answer (score 1):

Because [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) class implements `Parcelable`  interface, so instead of using `Bundle. putStringArrayList` use [Bundle.putParcelableArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)) to send ArrayList which contains class object which is implementing `Parcelable`  interface. Use

```
b.putParcelableArrayList("array_list5",coordinates);
```

> How to use parcelable with List or ArrayList - What is
>   the syntax?

Do it as:

```
ArrayList<String> arrCoordinates = new ArrayList<>(coordinates.size());
arrCoordinates.addAll(coordinates);
b.putParcelableArrayList("array_list5",arrCoordinates);
```

and get `array_list5` as from Bundle

```
ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates = b.getParcelableArrayList("array_list5");
```

Comment: Can you please explain for first, and second activities for both List<String> and ArrayList<LatLng>? Is "intent.putExtras(b);" correct?

Comment: @Zac1: my question is `Why casting every object to ArrayList<String> ? `

Comment: Only ArrayList<String> is supported with method putStringArrayList and there is no other method for List<String>

Comment: Yes, the second arraylist is not received by the second activity. Why? Please look at the comments in my code. ALSO, using parcelable on List<String> gives error, "The method putParcelableArrayList(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>)"

Comment: @Zac1: ok then use `(ArrayList<LatLng>)coordinates `

Comment: How to use parcelable for List<String> ?

Comment: @Zac1: why not using `ArrayList<String>` instead of `List<String>` because `Bundle. putParcelableArrayList ` accept only ArrayList as second parameter

Comment: Can you please read my question again, 1)The second value "array_list2" is NOT getting received. Why? and 2) You answered this, thanks. Now, my 3rd questions is, 3) How to use parcelable with List<String> or ArrayList<String> - What is the syntax?

Comment: @Zac1: as here `b.putStringArrayList("array_list1",(ArrayList<String>)Names);     
b.putStringArrayList("array_list2",(ArrayList<String>)City);` both `Names` and `City` is different so it's not possible as you are saying `array_list2` is returning same result as `array_list1` until both Names` and `City`  List contents are not same

Comment: Thanks, that worked. There was a typo in my code... I was displaying testList1.toString() twice.